# What's wrong with my Android multi-threading?

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, android-anr-dialog

I have an app that sends and receives data from a server.  Each of these requests is made by creating a new thread to prevent locking up the UI.  On my device and in testing I'm not getting any ANRs, but it appears other users will encounter them from time to time.

In one example, looking at my ANR reports in the Play store it shows that I've received a few ANRs from my login function.

When a user enters their credentials and presses the login button, onCreate calls a login() function which retrieves additional information about the user. The code contains the following:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UserClient userClient = application.getUserClient();

            final Map<String, Object> user = userClient.getUser();

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Login.this.hideLoadingThrobber();

                if (user != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, AccountOverview.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    showLoginFailed();
                }
            }
          });
        }
    }).start();
```

userClient.getUser() looks like this:

```
public Map<String, Object> getUser() {
    RestClient client = getRestClient();
    String result = client.queryRESTurl("/user/");
    if (result != null && !result.equals("login failed")) {
        return JsonParser.toMap(result);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

From all I can tell, this is properly set up to prevent any kind of ANR but it still pops up now and then for some users.

Is there anything that looks out of the ordinary or that I'm doing wrong?  Should I be handling my threading differently?

Comment: run() still runs on the UI thread.  You should use start().  You could demonstrate this in testing by using thread.sleep(10000).  Bet you get an ANR...

Comment: I am not able to see anything out of ordinary. Do you have any other portion of code that might lead to an ANR?

Comment: Use `StrictMode` to see if you do anything obviously evil on the main application thread.

Comment: @Simon When I try to change run() to start() I get the following warning: "The type new Runnable(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Runnable.run()"

Comment: Why not use ASynchTask and lock the UI yourself? If find it much easier to use.